# Cannot create a VM with accessible network interface

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-17.10

I started to create a new VM for developement, cause my ubuntu 14.4 seems out of date.

I desicided to switch to ubuntu 17.10 for the future but fail on first installation.

This is my vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = false
        vb.memory = "1024"
    end

    config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1710"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: false
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.37.200"

end
```

And during the provisioning I got this

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifdown 'eth1' || true
/sbin/ip addr flush dev 'eth1'
# Remove any previous network modifications from the interfaces file
sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,$ d' /etc/network/interfaces > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre
sed -ne '/^#VAGRANT-END/,$ p' /etc/network/interfaces | tac | sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-END/,$ d' | tac > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post

cat \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-entry \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post \
  > /etc/network/interfaces

rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre
rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-entry
rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post

/sbin/ifup 'eth1'

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

bash: line 4: /sbin/ifdown: No such file or directory
bash: line 20: /sbin/ifup: No such file or directory
```

The machine is not available via the hosting windows. Do I have to install something before provisioning? Or do you prefer another machine template from hashicorb?

Regards
n00n

Answer (score 6):

Vagrant cannot be used with Ubuntu 17.10 at the moment, due to the removal of the traditional networking configuration tools and files: `/sbin/ifup` and `/sbin/ifdown`.

But you can create vagrant VM with a network interface with the following workaround:

**1.**
Add installing `ifupdown` into your Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

$provision_script = <<PROVISION
    apt-get -y update
    apt-get install ifupdown -y
PROVISION

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $provision_script
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = false
        vb.memory = "1024"
    end

    config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1710"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: false
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.37.200"
end
```

**2.**
Create vagrant VM:

```
vagrant up
```

Of course it fails with the error in question.

**3.**
Start provision script inside just created VM. It installs package `ifupdown` with necessary files:

```
vagrant provision
```

**4.**
And now reload your VM:

```
vagrant reload
```

Comment: Works fine in my ubuntu 18.04 with VirtualBox 5.1.38r122592 and Vagrant 2.0.2. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

For RHEL box, you can add the `nm_controlled` to get it to work:

```
qa.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.11.12.2", nm_controlled: "yes"
```

Refer to the vagrant source code [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/5b501a3fb05ed0ab16cf10991b3df9d231edb5cf/plugins/guests/redhat/cap/configure_networks.rb).

It works for me on MacOS 13.2.1 (Ventura), Virtualbox 7.0.6, vagrant 2.3.4.